# why would python3 recursive function return null

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I have this function that when hitting a rate limit will call itself again.  It should eventually succeed and return the working data.  It works normally then rate limiting works as expected, and finally when the data goes back to normal I get:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
def grabPks(pageNum):
    # cloudflare blocks bots...use scraper library to get around this or build your own logic to store and use a manually generated cloudflare session cookie... I don't care 

    req = scraper.get("sumurl.com/"+str(pageNum)).content
    if(req == b'Rate Limit Exceeded'):
        print("adjust the rate limiting because they're blocking us :(")
        manPenalty = napLength * 3
        print("manually sleeping for {} seconds".format(manPenalty))
        time.sleep(manPenalty)
        print("okay let's try again... NOW SERVING {}".format(pageNum))
        grabPks(pageNum)
    else:
        tree = html.fromstring(req)
        pk = tree.xpath("/path/small/text()")
        resCmpress = tree.xpath("path/a//text()")
        resXtend = tree.xpath("[path/td[2]/small/a//text()")
        balance = tree.xpath("path/font//text()")
        return pk, resCmpress, resXtend, balance
```

I've tried to move the return to outside of the else scope but then it throws:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'pk' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your top level `grabPks` doesnt return anything if it is rate limited.

Think about this:

1. Call `grabPks()`
2. You're rate limited so you go into the if statement and call `grabPks()` again.
3. This time it succeeds so `grabPks()` returns the value to the function above it.
4. The first function now falls out of the if statement, gets to the end of the function and returns nothing.

Try `return grabPks(pageNum)` instead inside your `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

well okay... I needed to return grabPKs to make it play nice...:

```
def grabPks(pageNum):
    # cloudflare blocks bots...use scraper library to get around this or build your own logic to store and use a manually generated cloudflare session cookie... I don't care 

    req = scraper.get("sumurl.com/"+str(pageNum)).content
    if(req == b'Rate Limit Exceeded'):
        print("adjust the rate limiting because they're blocking us :(")
        manPenalty = napLength * 3
        print("manually sleeping for {} seconds".format(manPenalty))
        time.sleep(manPenalty)
        print("okay let's try again... NOW SERVING {}".format(pageNum))
        return grabPks(pageNum)
    else:
        tree = html.fromstring(req)
        pk = tree.xpath("/path/small/text()")
        resCmpress = tree.xpath("path/a//text()")
        resXtend = tree.xpath("[path/td[2]/small/a//text()")
        balance = tree.xpath("path/font//text()")
        return pk, resCmpress, resXtend, balance
```